# how to acquire a structure of eax register in c++

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, cpu-registers, unions

if i use struct, it will take up memory unlike the actual register where al and ah together make ax register and the eax register merges with the ax register. if i use union, al and ah values will be in the same place where in real, they are 2 separate registers. how can i acquire a structure of the eax register? i have noticed in the dos.h header (which is in c) has "union regs" which has the structure i need. but on my machine, there is no such "union regs". till now, i've tried :-

```
struct regs {
    uint32 eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi, edi, esp, ebp;
    uint16 ax, bx, cx, dx;
    uint8 ah, al, bh, bl, ch, cl, dh, dl;
};
```

Comment: If you want a union where you could write `ax` and read `ah`, that's [undefined behavior](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-pun) in C++ anyway.

Comment: no, i just want a structure which is similar to eax register's structure

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is there some example of what you need it for?

Comment: in the eax register, 16 lsb are ax register, 8 msb of that register is ah register an the other 8 bits are the al register. i want a structure like this in c++.

Comment: Let's assume that C++ has no such data structure. What do you need it for? Maybe that thing can be achieved in a different way.

Comment: no, for like, error debugging

Comment: in ubuntu, if an application fails, in the report window, we have an option (or whatever you call it) called registers and shows the values of the registers captured at the moment

Comment: Maybe you could look into inline assembly

Comment: If you want a struct with ax, ah, and al in it overlapping each other, you have to combine struct and union (but see drateniks comment about undefined behavior). You can do it better by defining a class, which holds a 64-bit-value, but allows you to also read the smaller components. If you want to access the actual processor registers, see the comment about inline assembly.

Comment: @Sebastian , that solved my problem `union {int32 eax; union {int16 ax; struct {int8 ah, al;};};} reg_eax;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sebastian mentioned that I should combine structs and unions to get that kind of a architecture. I was not sure if nested structs and unions would but I tried and it worked:-

```
union {int32 eax; union {int16 ax; struct {int8 ah, al;};};} reg_eax;
```

Note that using a struct or union without a name works as long as a different member of the same level does not have the same name.

Comment: Just beware of that anonymous `struct` is standard C l, but only supported as a non-standard extension by a few compilers on C++. And, casting objects with `union` is quite common in low-level programming, but is undefined behaviour due to aliasing-rules. So it can stop to work with other compile flags or on another compiler.